# Function to count valid responses

Tags: python, pandas

I have a large df with a structure like this

```
id q2 q7 q3 q5 q12
1  1  2  2  9  
2  2  4  8  9
3     5
4  3
5  7           2
```

I want to create a function in which due to the size od the dataframe I can input a start and end variable and it will count total number of that DO NOT have missing variables. For the whole dataframe I can use

```
valid = np.sum(df.notnull().sum(axis=1)>0)
```

But is it possible to create a function that takes for example q2 (starts) and q3 (ends) and returns only for that subset of variables (q2,q7,q3) how many non missing rows exist?

So calling valid(df,q2,q7) returns 5 as there are no full missing rows, but calling valid(df,q5,q12) returns 3 as there are 2 missing rows.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can slice with `loc`. Also, for boolean data, `sum()>0` is equivalent to `any()`

```
df.loc[:,'q2':'q3'].notnull().any(axis=1).sum()
# 5

df.loc[:,'q3':'q12'].notnull().any(axis=1).sum()
# 3
```